# Are these C++ terms correct?

Tags: c++

I'm reading a book, the Primer guide to C++.

I think I got the hang of it upto a point, I just want to clarify a few things.

1. It says that a `class` is like a data type (A data type being `int`, `char`, ect ..) and that an `Object`/Instance is like a variable. Is this true?
2. What is a data form?
3. What part of a statement is the declaration? Is it the `data type` + `the variable`, and the `=` is the assignment?

Comment: I don't know; I thought the questions would be simple to answer and I took time to write out the questions so they could be returned efficiently.

Comment: I do think it's a little harsh.  If he's already reading a book and he's confused they're valid questions.

Comment: Please vote this up, it is too harsh indeed to downvote like that. He's learning C++ and asking questions, not pasting a homework for us to solve.

Comment: People should be more careful about downvoting.  I actually used experts-exchange instead of SO for about 2 years because the first few questions I tried to post on SO were so brutalized :p Now I love it here though, haha.

Comment: +6 -7, wow. New record for me.

Comment: Hah yeah I came from Experts-Exchange immediately after I began their trial and saw how it has changed for the worse; I've been a member previously a few years ago, I asked a question here before and got a good response, while this question got bombed after came back and checked in a min, ha :P

Comment: EE is good if you're on a popular topic. It's basically SO with free T-shirts as long as you answer 2 questions a month. I got lazy for a few months and they billed me though, so that's when I swithced :) SO is faster for decent answers usually anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not quite.

A class is "like a data type" in the sense that it's a template for the creation of an object, but it isn't itself an object that you can use.

When you use that template to create an instance of an object, then you can make use of that object.  You may create as many instances as you want - you can think of those instances as variables.

For example:

```
class Person
{
    public:
        Person() : name("Joe Bloggs") {}

        std::string getName() { return name; } 

        void setName(std::string n) { name = n; }

    private:
        std::string name;    
};
```

This is a class definition for a Person.  It is not a variable.  You cannot call setName on it because it doens't exist yet.  But when you do:

```
int main()
{
    Person p, q;
    p.setName("Jill Bloggs");
    q.setName("Bob King");
    std::cout << p.getName() << " " << q.getName() << std::endl;
}
```

You created two instances of people that you can assign to, change, and use - they are variables called instances.

I have no idea what "data form" means, ignore that.

As for declaration - the declaration states that an instance of something will be present.  For example, if you were creating a class, and your header file had:

```
class foo
{
    public:

        foo(int value);

        void bar();

    private:
        int x;
};
```

You are declaring that you have a function called bar that returns void and that you have an integer called x.

No memory is allocated for the variable, x, and no definition is provided or bar, so they're just declarations.  Your source file would probably provide  definition for bar like:

```
void foo::bar()
{
    //some code
}
```

and a constructor definiton for foo that would initialize x with a value and control how it was created (with an initializer list):

```
foo::foo(int value) : x(value)
{
    //some code
}
```

Comment: Haha thanks a lot for taking the time to explain!

Comment: No problem.  It gets easier - you'll find that you can rewrite your 2nd year college final project that took 3 months in 15 minutes in your senior year :) (assuming you're in college, haha).

Comment: The only meaning for "data form" I can think of is a box to input data.

Comment: To grab the specific quote;

"That is, a class definition describes a DATA FORM and how it can be used, whereas an object is an entity created according to the DATA FORM specification."

Comment: Yeah, haha. I actually thought of XML defining the form of your data when I saw it, but in terms of C++ I've got no clue.

Comment: Ah, okay.  So they mean by data form what I meant by template - for the record, template can mean something completely different (more copmplex) in C++, so don't let me confuse you either.  Look into generic programming & check out a std::vector to see what I mean by that.